# Find the differential equation given three solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Three answers of a linear 2nd order differential equation $L[y]=g(t)$ are:

$y_1=3e^t+e^{t^2}$

$y_2=7e^t+e^{t^2}$

$y_3=5e^t+e^{-t^3}+e^{t^2}$

Find the answer of $L(y)=3t^4 + t^2$ where $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=-1$

My attempt: There is this theory that if $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ are the Basic solutions of the homogeneous substitution equation, and $y(t)$ is a solution of the equation, the answer is:
$c_1 y_1(t) + c_2 y_2(t) + y(t)$

How can i use this idea to solve the problem?

Comment: Hint: you can find $L$ by eliminating $c_1,c_2$ from $y=c_1e^t+c_2e^{t^2}$ (multiply by $e^{-t}$ to isolate $c_1$, and differentiate; then divide by the factor of $c_2$ and differentiate). I don't guarantee that this is the shortest way to the solution.

Comment: With solutions involving functions such as $e^{t^2}$ for example, you **cannot** have solutions with constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ (real numbers). They should be functions $c_1(t)$ and $c_2(t)$ (see the method of variation of constants).

Comment: @Pat Bol See my comment.

Comment: @JeanMarie: $(2t-1)y''-(4t^2+1)y'+(4t^2-2t+2)y=0$ has the general solution $c_1e^t+c_2e^{t^2}$.

Comment: @Pat Bol : Thanks, very interesting. I wasn't thinking along these lines (I see how you have obtained it). It remains to check that the third solution with its $e^{t^3}$ term is a solution of this equation... Please transform this comment into an answer !

Comment: @JeanMarie: $g(t)=(18t^5+3t^4-5t^2+4t+2)e^{-t^3}$, but this is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: A similar issue [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1055564).

Comment: Are you sure about exponent $3$ in $e^{-t^3}$ in the third solution ?

Comment: Another similar issue [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1734427).

Comment: @Boshra Alef Please, can you react ?